# SCSS - адаптивность через медиа-запросы

Tags: css, sass

У меня есть простая вёрстка а-ля калькулятор. Для него надо обеспечить адаптивность. Это логично делать с помощью медиа-запросов.

Мой подход: имеется файл `_config.scss`, в котором содержатся все глобальные переменные вроде цветов кнопок, шрифтов и их размеров. Потом, в остальных файлах, я подключаю `@use 'config'` и устанавливаю все нужные стили из него, например: `background-color: config.$keyboard_color`

Вроде всё красиво, но, когда я пытаюсь изменять эти переменные из медиа-запросов, получается ерунда: он применяет все изменения переменных, вне зависимости от того, выполняется этот запрос или нет.

Пример ниже, где размер шрифта становится 15em, при том, что у меня как бы не `embossed`-устройство:

```
$button_color: #5F6062;
$button_color_darker: #3F4143;
$button_color_orange: #FD9E2B;
$button_font_size: 5em;
$button_font_color: white;
$button_font: "sans-serif";

$display_color: #2B2D2F;
$display_font_size: 6em;
$display_padding: 15px 30px;
$display_font_color: white;
$display_font: "sans-serif";

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    $button_font_size: 2em !global; 
}
 
@media (embossed) {
    $button_font_size: 15em !global; 
}
```

Я понимаю, что от препроцессора этого следовало ожидать (хотя поведение действительно неочевидное), но, в таком случае, какие есть альтернативы?
Мне эта идея с конфигурационным файлом кажется очень стройной, логичной и масштабируемой, а альтернатив я особо и не вижу...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилятор препроцессора не создаёт в файле css эти переменные.
Поэтому поэтому код не работает, создайте новые и используйте их в медиазапросах, или используйте нативные, не забывая посматривать в caniuse https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables

```css
:root {
  --font-size: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  :root {
    --font-size: 20px;
  }
}
h1 {
  font-size: var(--font-size);
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
```

Comment: Это действительно работает. Спасибо. Я ожидал, что препроцессор сможет сам построить медиазапросы или установить переменные CSS, ведь у него есть информация о том, как и где я их использую.

Comment: А в общем и целом, такой подход к построению адаптивности можно считать хорошей идеей, или мне стоит взглянуть на какие-нибудь другие?

Answer (score 1):

можно так :)

**P.S.** Если используете *CSS Custom Properties*, то лучше захватить библиотеку, *cssVars* называется, вроде как, она включает в себя поддержку IE

```css
@mixin color() {
  @media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
    color: green;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    color: red;
  }
}

p { @include color; }
```

```html
<p>Hello, world!</p>
```

Comment: О, спасибо, так тоже интересно. Жаль, что SASS не предоставляет достаточно лаконичных средств сделать это.

Comment: А вообще, как люди обычно делают на продакшене? Есть какие-нибудь "лучшие практики"? :)

Comment: @witaway, не знаю, каждый делает по своему, обычно числовые переменные не заводят, чаще всего встречал цвета, брейкпоинты, но, в принципе, можно завести юнит-переменную и с ней манипулировать (умножать/делить/складывать/вычитать)

Comment: Понял, спасибо за информацию. :)